# Trying to add responsiveness to a website using bootstrap grid system

Tags: html, css

Using the information from this link....http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp ... I am trying to apply it to my html code. I am using 2 columns so both col should be 6 so that they equal 12. But I am not sure where to place all the code from the bootstrap link above..into my code for this website. code is below.

Comment: _"code is below."_ ...erm

Answer (score 0):

Place them inside the body tag for sure. Though your question isn't clear. But all the div tags are placed inside the body tags as and when you require them